# Range feature in indexing packages?

Tags: indexing

The Chicago Manual of Style says that index  locators are usually pages but can also be paragraph or section numbers. It seems a good idea to use a package's range feature (if available) e.g. "For example if you have a paragraph describing the mating habits of professors, have `\index{professors!mating habits|(}` at the beginning and `\index{professors!mating habits|)}` at the end of the paragraph" (Emma Pease).

It seems like the indxcite package has something like this available `\indexcite[(]{latexcomp}.`

"If a citation is refered to over several paragraphs you may want to
index the whole range of text. In this case you need to use three commands:  one to generate the citation`\cite{latexcomp};` one to mark the begining of the text to be indexed and one to mark the end of the text to be indexed."

What other indexing packages have this functionality?  All of them - is it more to do with makeindex/xindy???

Comment: The `(` and `)` open and close range markers are part of `makeindex`'s syntax, which is also recognised by `xindy` when it's in `makeindex` mode (`texindy`). `xindy`'s native format marks up start and end ranges differently. It's a bit of an open ended question as it comes down to a combination of the indexing application and the package used to interface with it.

Comment: It seems to work OK with xindy and imakeidx.  Maybe the question would be better framed as "Are there any known combinations that are incompatible"?

Comment: I think that `imakeidx`'s `xindy` option actually means use `texindy`, so that it uses the same syntax.

Comment: Yes, the manual says that texindy is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** As long as the package interface provides a way of setting the encap, then explicit range formations should be possible if the indexing is performed by an indexing application that recognises `(` and `)` as start and end range markers or if the package can correctly interpret and convert range markup to the appropriate syntax.

---

Most indexing packages use `\index`, which is actually a kernel command:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
Foo\index{foo|(}.

\chapter{Another}
Foo\index{foo|)}.

\end{document}
```

(The kernel doesn't provide `\printindex`.) All `\index` does is write the argument to the `.idx` file (opened with `\makeindex`) with the corresponding page number:

```
\indexentry{foo|(}{1}
\indexentry{foo|)}{2}
```

This is `makeindex` syntax, which can also be processed with `texindy`. Indexing packages typically only modify `\index` if multiple indexes are supported. For example, [`imakeidx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) redefines `\index` to have an optional argument, which indicates the associated file, but the mandatory argument is still in `makeindex` syntax.

The default `page-ranges` module used by `texindy` requires a minimum range separation of three. In the following, it doesn't form a range because the range spans only two pages:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
Foo\index{foo|(}.

\chapter{Another}
Foo\index{foo|)}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: Index F foo, 1, 2]

Switching to the `book` class makes the range span three pages:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
Foo\index{foo|(}.

\chapter{Another}
Foo\index{foo|)}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: Index F foo, 1–3]

The `\glossary` command has a similar function:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeglossary

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
Foo\glossary{foo|(}.

\chapter{Another}
Foo\glossary{foo|)}.

\end{document}
```

The `.glo` file contains:

```
\glossaryentry{foo|(}{1}
\glossaryentry{foo|)}{2}
```

So it's still using `makeindex` syntax.

The [`nomencl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) package provides `\nomenclature`, which also writes indexing information, but in this case it's more restricted as it enforces a particular syntax. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
Foo\nomenclature{$\pi$}{pi}.

\end{document}
```

The `.nlo` file contains:

```
\nomenclatureentry{a$\pi$@[{$\pi$}]\begingroup pi\nomeqref {0}|nompageref}{1}
```

There's no way of overriding the `nompageref` encap, which means there's no way of adding range markup.

The [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package also doesn't use or redefine the kernel commands. (The precursor `glossary` package used `\glossary` and I think early versions of `glossaries` used a modified version, but it doesn't any more.) In this case the encap is specified with the `format` key, so it's possible to form ranges:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={sample}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\Gls[format=(]{foo}.

\chapter{Another}
\Gls[format=)]{foo}.

\end{document}
```

The `.glo` file now looks like:

```
\glossaryentry{foo?\glossentry{foo}|(setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{foo?\glossentry{foo}|)setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}
```

With the `xindy` package option it switches to `xindy`'s native syntax:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={sample}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\Gls[format=(]{foo}.

\chapter{Another}
\Gls[format=)]{foo}.

\end{document}
```

The `.glo` file now looks like:

```
(indexentry :tkey (("foo" "\\glossentry{foo}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" :open-range)
(indexentry :tkey (("foo" "\\glossentry{foo}") ) :locref "{}{2}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" :close-range)
```

The "noidx" version doesn't support range formations. It uses TeX to sort and collate rather than a dedicated indexing application. If ranges are used, the result is a bit weird.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={sample}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\Gls[format=(]{foo}.

\chapter{Another}
\Gls[format=)]{foo}.

\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: Glossary foo sample. 1,2]

The [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package provides another indexing method:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={example-glossaries-brief}% use test data in example-glossaries-brief.bib
]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\Gls[format=(]{lorem}.

\chapter{Another}
\Gls[format=)]{lorem}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

This doesn't create any additional files. The indexing information is in the `.aux` file:

```
\glsxtr@record{lorem}{}{page}{(}{1}
...
\glsxtr@record{lorem}{}{page}{)}{2}
```

The indexing is performed by [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) which recognises `(` and `)` as open and close range markers.

It should be possible to combine `(` or `)` with a formatting command. For example, returning to `\index` and `makeindex`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
Foo\index{foo|(textbf}.

\chapter{Another}
Foo\index{foo|)textbf}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This puts the entire range in bold (start page, en dash and end range).

[image: Index foo, 1–2]

`makeindex` tolerates a missing format at the end of the range:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
Foo\index{foo|(textbf}.

\chapter{Another}
Foo\index{foo|)}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This produces the same result as before.

`makeindex` doesn't like a conflicting format:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
Foo\index{foo|(textbf}.

\chapter{Another}
Foo\index{foo|)emph}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This triggers a warning

```
## Warning (input = test.idx, line = 2; output = test.ind, line = 3):
   -- Range closing operator has an inconsistent encapsulator emph.
```

and discards the conflict, acting as though the end range was `)textbf` and so produces the same result as above.

With `xindy`, the range separator isn't included in the formatting command, so only the start and end page appear in bold, not the en dash:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
Foo\index{foo|(textbf}.

\chapter{Another}
Foo\index{foo|)textbf}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: Index F foo, 1–3]

`xindy` also doesn't like mis-matched formats:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
Foo\index{foo|(textbf}.

\chapter{Another}
Foo\index{foo|)}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This gives the warning:

```
WARNING: Found no :close-range matching an already opened one!
         Location-reference is 1 in keyword (foo).
         Maybe I lost some of the regular location-references.

WARNING: Found a :close-range in the index that wasn't opened
         before!
         Location-reference is 3 in keyword (foo)
         I'll continue and ignore this.
```

In this case the range is lost:

[image: Index F foo,]

`bib2gls` also puts the start and end pages in bold (but not the separator):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={example-glossaries-brief}% use test data in example-glossaries-brief.bib
]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\Gls[format={(textbf}]{lorem}.

\chapter{Another}
\Gls[format={)textbf}]{lorem}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: Glossary lorem ipsum 1–2]

`bib2gls` allows mismatched formats in ranges:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={example-glossaries-brief}% use test data in example-glossaries-brief.bib
]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\Gls[format={(textbf}]{lorem}.

\chapter{Another}
\Gls[format={)}]{lorem}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

There's no warning in this case. The start page is in bold and the end page is in the normal surrounding font. Similarly, in the following the start page is bold and the end page is emphasized:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={example-glossaries-brief}% use test data in example-glossaries-brief.bib
]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\Gls[format={(textbf}]{lorem}.

\chapter{Another}
\Gls[format={)emph}]{lorem}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: Glossary lorem ipsum 1–2]

Comment: Wow!  Can I plagarize that for my doctoral thesis?

Comment: @DLyons If you want some further tests, the [`testidx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/testidx) package is designed to cause encap conflicts to test indexing applications. You can even get the dummy blocks to appear in reverse order with `\testidx[\tstidxmaxblocks-1]` to test how the application deals with close before open encaps.

Comment: @Nicola-TalbotThe "nomenclature" is particularly interesting - I didn't know it existed!  I have terms that clearly belong there and, so far, I've handled them using a mixture of acronyms and a textual Notation section.  It should probably have occurred to me - many a Maths/Stats book has pages devoted their specialized nomenclature.

Comment: @DLyons [this document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/sample-multi2.pdf) was created using `glossaries-extra` and `bib2gls`. It includes a mixture of various types of terms.